# How do you convert an image into a number in python using pytesseract

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been trying to convert an image into a string/integer using pytesseract. The only problem is every time I run the code nothing happens. I changed the image into a text image reading "TEXT" and pytesseract detected it fine. Here is what I was using in order to convert the image into a string. I also included the image that I've been using.

[image: NumberTest]

`bal = pytesseract.image_to_string(balIm)
print(bal)`

I don't know what else to try the only other thing I could think of would be to try another OCR, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the Page Segmentation Mode (PSM) to mode 6 which will set the OCR to detect a single uniform block of text.

Specifically, do:

```
bal = pytesseract.image_to_string(balIm, config='--psm 6')
```

This should give you what you need.  In fact, I tried running this on your image and it gives me what I'm looking for.  Note that I downloaded your image that you provided above first and read in the image offline on my local machine:

```
In [8]: import pytesseract

In [9]: from PIL import Image

In [10]: balIm = Image.open('wC62s.png')

In [11]: pytesseract.image_to_string(balIm, config='--psm 6')
Out[11]: '0.03,'
```

---

As a final note to you, if you see that Tesseract doesn't quite work for you out of the box, consider trying one of their Page Segmentation Modes to help increase accuracy: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method.  For completeness, I'll make this available to you below.

```
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

When you run `image_to_string`, specify an input parameter `config` that takes in a PSM you want to operate in.  Try some of these until you get it to work for your image.  Make sure you use `--psm` in the `config` parameter prior to executing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked first try and even worked when I applied it to another application.

Comment: @chessyChad1999 You're welcome - if you no longer need help and your question has been answered, please consider accepting this answer to let the community know you are finished with this issue.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work